# Instalação GraphQL com erro

Tags: npm, graphql

Estou recebendo este erro ao tentar instalar o GraphQL

> ```
> npm ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/graphql/graphql-js.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
> npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=No such file or directory
> npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No such file or directory
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
> ```

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LES\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-17T16_16_58_780Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver isso?

Comment: Qual comando você está executando?